# In Memory database algorithm/design/logic in java

Tags: java, database-design, indexing

The problem statement is as follows, Supposed to be done in java,

I have collection, arrayList of `Person` class, i.e

```java
List<Person> lisOfPersons = new ArrayList<Person>();
```

where Person is,

```java
public class Person{
    int age;
    String name;
    //constuctor and setters and getters
}
```

Now, I want to use this as my cache and create a lib or wrapper utility around this collection. this utility is supposed to have/provide/expose three methods/API `findByName`, `findByAge`, `findByAgeAndName`.

Iterating over the collection is every time is no no thing. I am expecting somthing like/around indexing and rearranging the data in `HashMap`, or Heap or Tree. But here I need to create three indexes at least for every method. Other options, that is why you are here

Comment: Either you want index searches or you don't.  You can reduce this to two indexes by having a nested index by name and then by age.  Have you actually benchmarked your searches and determined it is too slow, e.g. you know how many entries you will have, the upper limit of how long it can take and how long it takes with a brute force search, or are you just assuming it will be?

Comment: @PeterLawrey good remarks in general, but in this simply using a Map is a faster solution both in speed and coding time.

Comment: @Dariusz I would agree except in any case it would be a multi-map as it appears there can be multiple Person of the same age or name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `Map<Integer, List<Person>>` and `Map<String, List<Person>>` for quick searches.

Remember that the objects will not be copied into the map, you are only using references, so there is not *that* much memory overhead.

As for AgeAndName search you can use `Collection.retainAll()` function once you get results from both of those maps. Remember to clone the collection, because retain works in-place.

```
  Set<Person> unique = new Set<Person> ( mapName.get("name") );
  unique.retainAll( mapAge.get(11) );
  return unique;
```

Comment: `Map<Integer, List<Person>>` will be better ;-) That's how I would solve this too.

Comment: Thanks,... using map as indexes and retainAll would do,... to this time this seems to be the best known approach...